# WPF pass multiple parameters to command

Tags: c#, wpf, events, commandbinding

Suppose we have 2 comboboxes and one button. Button click should pass values of both comboboxes to viewmodel's command. How can I get values of two comboboxes and pass those two values to the command?

Answer (score 3):

If both Comboboxes are placed within the same Panel you can send reference to it and retrieve comboboxes by their names. It is not advisable since you are not supposed to deal with UI elements in ViewModel.

```
<StackPanel Name="StackPanel">
    <ComboBox Name="FirstComboBox"/>
    <ComboBox Name="SecondComboBox"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding YourCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=StackPanel}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Latter approach is to bind to comboboxes' values and by using converter create specific object of class which will be sent as Parameter.

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel Name="StackPanel">
    <ComboBox Name="FirstComboBox"/>
    <ComboBox Name="SecondComboBox"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding YourCommand}">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ComboBoxesToComboClassConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="FirstComboBox" Path="SelectedValue"/>
                <Binding ElementName="SecondComboBox" Path="SelectedValue"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**Converter:**

```
class Combo
{
    public string FirstComboBoxValue { get; set; }
    public string SecondComboBoxValue { get; set; }
}

class ComboBoxesToComboClassConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Combo()
        {
            FirstComboBoxValue = values[0].ToString(),
            SecondComboBoxValue = values[1].ToString()
        };
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In case you are using MVVM, every ComboBox Value is supposed to bind to property and therefore you would have both Command, associated with button, and desired properties in the same class so there would be no need to pass anything.

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, in MVVM pattern you could bind dependency properties to the ViewModel using the `{Binding ...}` statement. So you should add this

```
SelectedValue="{Binding ComboboxValue1, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and

```
SelectedValue="{Binding ComboboxValue2, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

into your comboboxes definition in View (XAML). Afterwards, when user changes something in them, `ComboboxValue1` and `ComboboxValue2` properties will be notified about that. And now you may feel free to operate with these values in command handler in the ViewModel which bound to your button.